# Reverse engineering from c code to sequence chart

Tags: c

I have a c code and I want to extract some patterns of code which contains instructions of communication etc and build a sequence chart from that.

Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: yes. By inspecting the code and using your grey matter...

Comment: That's a strange definition of "reverse engineering".  I'd normally consider that "understanding".

Comment: I wasn't defining "reverse engineering".

Comment: I wasn't talking to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pic2plot which is part of GNU plotutils. You need log/trace what talks to what, to a file and then you can render it with pic2plot. I've done this for a python program, but there is no reason why you can't do that with a C program.

[image: sequence diagram]
<sub>(source: [umlgraph.org](http://www.umlgraph.org/doc/seq-eg.gif))</sub>

see http://www.umlgraph.org/

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to use doxygen with the following options:

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
```

You will get a very nice call and caller graphs of functions which can help a great deal with understanding the code. A call graph is more common and useful for C code than a sequence chart.

[call graph http://pedro.larroy.com/files/example.png](http://pedro.larroy.com/files/example.png)